# Mac install and open mysql using terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, terminal

I downloaded the mysql dmg file and went through the wizard to run. Done. I have also started mysql server under system preferences.

The purpose of me doing this is to work through the exercises of my SQL text book. The terminal commands are new to me but I think once I can actually get started, working through the exercises should be OK.

From researching the web the various blogs tell me to navigate to to the mysql folder in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/mysql
```

Fine. Then it gets a little less clear as nearly each article has a different set of instructions on how to proceed. I was fiddling with it yesterday and was prompted for a password - what is the default mysql password?

Could someone give me the steps to get up and running with mysql via the terminal?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

*(Updated for 2017)*

When you installed MySQL it generated a password for the root user.  You can connect using

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

and type in the generated password.

Previously, the `root` user in MySQL used to not have a password and could only connect from localhost.  So you would connect using

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

Comment: I am getting: -bash: mysql: command not found Why might this be?

Comment: As of 2016, MySQL by generates has a password for root user. So the above command would be /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p (OSX)

Comment: This answer may apply when you don't have a password. However, at least as of now MySQL generates a password automatically by default when you install.

Comment: It can sometimes be at `/usr/local/bin/mysql`, type `which mysql` to find out where mysql has been installed, and also it does not apply if you have installed using homebrew

Comment: Mine is in /usr/local/my-sqlshell/bin/mysqlsh
My OS is MacOS Catalina :)

Answer (score 67):

open terminal and type

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

then close terminal and open a new terminal and type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

hit enter, and it will ask you for password

I have found this solution on https://teamtreehouse.com/community/says-mysql-command-not-found

now to set new password type

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Comment: I have High Sierra and I have to modify the first line, only you have to remove "/bin" in the first path:

sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql > /etc/paths.d/mysql'

Thanks, for the tip!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution :)

Answer (score 11):

In the terminal, I typed:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

I was then prompted to enter the temporary password that was given to me upon completion of the installation.

Answer (score 10):

In MacOS, Mysql's executable file is located in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` and you can easily login to it with the following command:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

But this is a very long command and very boring, so you can add mysql path to Os's Environment variable and access to it much easier.

**For `macOS Catalina` and later**

Starting with macOS Catalina, Mac devices use `zsh` as the default login shell and interactive shell and you have to update `.zprofile` file in your home directory.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"' >> ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zprofile
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

**For `macOS Mojave` and earlier**

Although you can always switch to `zsh`, `bash` is the default shell in macOS Mojave and earlier and with `bash` you have to update `.bash_profile` file.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

Comment: Thank you for this updated version for macOS Catalina!

Comment: This works fine, but when I get prompted to input the Password, I don't have one. Is it meant to be in Keychain? What if I don't have one? Is there a way to recover that pasword? I am on Mac Mojave

Comment: @HoracioNesman: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46724559/3881354 helps you

Answer (score 7):

1. install homebrew via terminal
2. `brew install mysql`

Comment: how can I see the path of My SQL where it is installed? I wanna see `mysql/bin`

Answer (score 7):

In terminal

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

Close that and open new terminal

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Give your password

Answer (score 5):

This command works for me:

```
./mysql -u root -p
```

*(PS: I'm working on mac through terminal)*

Answer (score 5):

For mac OS `Catalina` :

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

This will prompt you to enter password of `mysql`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply type in Terminal

```
brew services start mysql
```

if you installed mysql via brew on mac

Answer (score 3):

If you have your MySQL server up and running, then you just need a client to connect to it and start practicing. One is the `mysql-client`, which is a command-line tool, or you can use `phpMyAdmin`, which is a web-based tool.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I seem to now be connected using Gary's terminal command above. 
When you say mysql-client does that mean the terminal? Google seems to really fail at explaining the search term "mysql-client".
Is mysql-client a particular product or interface provided by mysql?
*Confusion* Thanks for your help allt he same and for your patience - I am a learner!

Comment: mysql-client is a Linux package that provides the `mysql` command and client libraries.  On OS X, the dmg you downloaded and installed provides both the server `mysqld` and the client `mysql`, so you don't need a separate client package.

Answer (score 2):

This command works for me:

Command:

```
mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

Answer (score 1):

try with either of the 2 below commands

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot`
-- OR --
`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<version>/bin/mysql -uroot`

Answer (score 0):

using terminal insert following command

**mysql -u root -p**

after enter your root mysql password.