# How do I get my forgotten MySQL password from MySQL Workbench on macOS?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, keychain

I have forgotten my root mysql password. However, it is stored in MysqlWorkbench.

[image]
Is there any way to get it back? Thank you.

Comment: Does this work? https://www.macworld.com/article/2854475/how-to-recover-passwords-with-keychain-access.html

Comment: There are many ways to change this password, specially since the server is localhost. You can actually reset it without even knowing the previous one. Recovering it however will be complicated...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On macOS keywords are stored in the keychain. Hence you can open up the Keychain app, go to the Password section and enter `mysql` in the search box. A list of entries should come up with values of your MySQL connections you created in MySQL Workbench. Get the password from the entry you need (you have to enter your login password to see it).

Comment: On macOS Sierra 10.12.6, the name of the app is "Keychain Access"

Comment: Great. You have saved my day!