# How to get forgotten MySQL password from MySQL Workbench on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql-workbench, password-encryption

This question is essentially the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46720276/how-do-i-get-my-forgotten-mysql-password-from-mysql-workbench-on-macos), but for Windows 10.

[image]

I have checked the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-vault.html) and still have no clear answer. A step by step for viewing the password would be perfect and truly appreciated!

Answer (score 36):

First go check where your encrypted file is. Usually it is stored at `%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat`

Now that you have the file location, open up powershell and copy & paste the following sequence of commands (order is important):

```sh
$cipher = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat -AsByteStream -Raw
```

Hit Enter

```sh
$scope = [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser
```

Hit Enter

```sh
$mysqlpwd = [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect(
    $cipher, $null, $scope )
```

Hit Enter

```sh
[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($mysqlpwd)
```

Hit Enter

Now you can see the following output:

```
Mysql@X:Y@Z#DBUSER#DBPASSWORD
...
ssh@Z:22#SSHUSER#SSHPASSWORD
...
```

---

If you receive a TypeNotFound error:

> Unable to find type [System.Security...].

you may also need to run the following to get access to "System.Security"

```sh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
```

---

References:

- https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/5e10b42aa539155128bd97d54ed2cdd7ca283b34/library/forms/winforms/src/wf_utilities.cpp#L857
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-vault.html

Comment: Legend - thanks for this.  You may have to add the following to have access to System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData:  "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security"

Comment: This worked. Just a minor change to this command - `$cipher = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat -Encoding Byte` Instead run it as `$cipher = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat -AsByteStream` Reference https://github.com/PowerShell/GPRegistryPolicyParser/issues/5

Comment: i don't know how to get the encrypted file... Someone assist..

Comment: Amazing! - Now do we need to do anything to re-encrypt or undo those commands?

Comment: @Bubba No, because you only read the contents and don't write the unencrypted contents back to the file.

Comment: @L.John
God Bless You. 
Saved me from reinstalling the database :)

Comment: Incidentally, I was getting an error when running the first command with -AsByteStream but "$cipher = Get-Content $env:APPDATA\MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat -Encoding Byte" worked instead. I haven't updated Powershell on this version of Windows 10 so that might be why.

Answer (score 5):

I made a quick [Python solution](https://gist.github.com/huntfx/612550168254f4075897ec4665d64f1d) adapted from the link in Mike's answer, since the PowerShell answer didn't work for me.

```py
import os
import re
import win32crypt  # Requires pywin32 package

WORKBENCH_REGEX = re.compile('(?P<dbm>[A-z]+)@(?P<host>[A-z0-9._-]+):(?P<port>[0-9]+)\2(?P<user>[A-z0-9_-]+)\3(?P<password>.*)')

def read_workbench_user_data(file_path=None):
    if file_path is None:
        file_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'MySQL/Workbench/workbench_user_data.dat')

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        encrypted_data = file.read()
    decrypted_data = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_data, None, None, None, 0)
    decrypted_content = decrypted_data[1].decode('utf-8')
    return decrypted_content.split('\n')[:-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in read_workbench_user_data():
        match = WORKBENCH_REGEX.match(item)

        print(f'{match.group("dbm")}:')
        print(f'\tHost: {match.group("host")}:{match.group("port")}')
        print(f'\tUsername: {match.group("user")}')
        print(f'\tPassword: {match.group("password")}')
```

Here's how the output looks:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to view the stored passwords in MySQL Workbench on Windows. The implementation uses Windows encryption APIs and stores the encrypted passwords in an own file, which can only be decrypted by the same user on the same host, from which it was encrypted.

The only solution to get passwords out from that vault is to use the code which also [Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/forms/winforms/src/wf_utilities.cpp#L827) is using. That requires to write a small tool for this task.

Comment: "can only be decrypted by the same user on the same host" - it was encrypted by me on the host. How to decrypt is essentially my question.

Comment: I know your question. My answer addressed that with a bit extra info.