# Run MySQL Statement in MAC .bash file

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I am trying to run a text file in Mac using Terminal. That file will connect to MySQL Server and load CSV file to table. But when I am running the file in terminal, it is asking for MySQL password and in the next step giving error message "**MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'*hostaddress*' (using password: YES)**
".
I am new to Mac environment, so unable to find the solution.

Below is the sample:

```
#! /bin/bash

MysqlHost=server address
MysqlUser=user name
MysqlPass=password
MysqlPort=3306
MysqlDB=test


mysqlsh -h$MysqlHost -u$MysqlUser -D$MysqlDB --sql -e"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'/Users/Desktop/file.csv' INTO TABLE tab_list FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES "
```

The error I am getting :

```
MAC6s-MacBook-Air:extracts ABC$ ./batch_test.txt 
Please provide the password for 'root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx': 
qwerty
MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
(using password: YES)
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235558/713789 you need to pass like -u root -p password.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I don't think that this is the problem because MySQL obviously asks for the password as expected, and the command line seems correct to me.

Comment: @Binarus I read your answer and this is exactly what happen to me 1-2 week ago, there is multiple host in one mysql installation, one is localhost, another is 127.0.0.1 and last is ::1. I create a account on a host and looking at another one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be caused by several reasons, but this is the most likely one IMHO:

MySQL grants or denies access not only based on user name and password, but also based on the *host where the access comes **from***. In other words, you may encounter a situation where you can login to a MySQL database from a certain host using a certain user name and a certain password, but where you can *not* login to the same database from *another* host using the *same* user name and password.

Hence, the first thing I would do is checking the access rights for the respective user (which is `root` in your case). To do that, you would have to log in into your MySQL server (of course using a host and user name where this works) and look at least into the `db`, `host` and `user` tables of the `mysql` database.